# Calculating mean of Z in ROI in Surfer

Tags: contour, surfer

I was wondering if it was possible to calculate the mean of Z in a ROI in a Surfer Contour map.

To be more precise, I have the map of a chemical element of an object that I converted into a XYZ files. Then I used Surfer to converted it into a Krigeage grid of 3266 X 200 which I transformed into a contour map. I re-scale the axes of my map to produce a more "realistic looking" map that i can stack with a picture of my object.

Ultimately, i would like to be able to explore my map and zoom on a area of interest and get the mean of the Z values in this area (by drawing a polygon on the map for example).

Is it possible to do that on Surfer or do I have to export my file in QGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer if anybody have the same issue with Surfer 16

Load your contour map. Insert a new empty base map. Right click on the base map, then click on "Start editing". You can now draw your polygon on the map. Then select your polygon in the "Content" window on the left. Then go to Grid, Assign NoData. In the new window "Assign no data to grid", in "Input grid", choose your original grid, then in "NoData polygon boundary" choose the Base map you draw the polygon in. Then thick the boxes "NoData outside" and "Selected object only". Save the output grid. Then, you can indeed go to Grid, Grid Info, and here you can choose the newly created output grid wich contain the mean Z value inside your polygon.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can find the mean of the Z values in an area of a drawn polygon. To do this in Surfer

1. Create the contour map from your grid file.
2. Click **Home | Add to Map | Layer | Empty Base Layer**. A new layer called “Base(vector)” is added to the map.
3. Right click over that base layer and click **Start Editing**.
4. Draw the polygon over the area you want.
5. Right click over that base layer and click **Stop Editing**.
6. Click **Grids | Info | Grid Info**.
7. For the *Input Grid*, select the grid of the contours. For the *Polygon Boundary*, select the polygon in the base layer. Select *Inside* (to calculate the information inside the polygon) and click **OK**.
8. A grid report is created for the area inside the polygon. Scroll down to the **Univariate Grid Statistics** section to see the Mean of the Z values.

You can draw as many polygons on the map that you want in the Base layer, and select the one you want to use and in Grid Info, check the "Selected objects only" box so that you are only calculating the info for that one polygon and not all of them in the base layer.

[image: Select the polygon boundary in Grid Info]

Comment: I work on the last Surfer version (16). I did insert the empty base layer and draw my polygon on it, but when when I click on "Grid info", i can only select an input grid but not Polygon Boundary. Have i done something wrong ?

Comment: Go to File | About Surfer and be sure you are using the latest version of Surfer 16 (v16.6) The option to find the info inside a polygon was added in version 16.5. So if you are using 16.4 or earlier, it won't be there. If you need to update, you can click File | Online | Check for Update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's a good option too - you can assign NoData to the grid outside the polygon to create a new grid, and then use that grid to calculate the info statistics. That is how you would do it in all versions of Surfer previous to 16.5. However, as long as you are using version 16.5+, you shouldn't have to do that extra step of assigning NoData. You could just use the polygon with the grid file directly in Grid Info.  If you aren't seeing your polygon show up in the Grid Info dialog, you are welcome to email the SRF file to support@goldensoftware.com and we can see what the issue is. Thanks!